# Find the daily stock return percentage in R

Tags: r, return, percentage, stock

I am taking a column of historical stock prices and trying to find the percent return on stock. This would be accomplished through calculations such as todays stock price minus yesterdays stock price divided by yesterdays stock price. You could also divide the most current day and divide by the last and subtract by one.

I can find the difference between each day, but that is not my problem. I believe my teacher told me it is

```
x <- diff(log(theReturns))
```

Can you guys find the percent change in daily stock in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your vector is `v <- c(10, 20, 23, 15, 22, 30)` (this would be what you call `theReturns`, but I am using `v` for short here).

The difference between each day, which you already know how to get as you say, is

```
v[2:6] - v[1:5]
# 10  3 -8  7  8
```

In R there is another way to write this, using the function `diff` (see `?diff` for more details):

```
diff(v) == v[2:6] - v[1:5]
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Since you want to calculate the difference as a percentage of the previous day (i.e. the relative change), you simply need to divide this by `v[1:5]`

```
diff(v) / v[1:5]
# 1.0000000  0.1500000 -0.3478261  0.4666667  0.3636364
```

My guess is that you know how to do all that, but your confusion comes from your teacher introducing the `log` function in there. I don't think you necessarily have to use `log`, but it may  simplify things because of one of its properties, which is that log(x/y) = log(x) - log(y), for positive x, y. Using this (after a little bit of algebra), you can see that another way to calculate the relative change is

```
exp(diff(log(v))) - 1
```

since that evaluates to `exp(log(v[2:6]) - log(v[1:5])) - 1` which equals `(v[2:6] / v[1:5]) - 1` which in turn equals `(v[2:6] - v[1:5]) / v[1:5]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really like how you expanded the log equation. This gave me my answer    y <- cbind((-diff(log(stock1)))) I was mixing things up because my "theReturns" was the difference, but now it is a column of stock. TY!